# How can I get the WebDriver version during Testrun?

Tags: testing, frameworks, selenium, webdriver

I am writing on a testframework where the report should include the webdriver version of the test run. When using selenium there is the getEval("Selenium.version") method. But I find no way to read the version when using webdriver. Does anyone know a solution?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible by reading the VERSION.txt properties file. This seems hacky, but it's what the WebDriver developers do in SeleniumServer.java:

```java
final Properties p = new Properties();
p.load(getSeleniumResourceAsStream("/VERSION.txt"));
String rcVersion = p.getProperty("selenium.rc.version");
String rcRevision = p.getProperty("selenium.rc.revision");
String coreVersion = p.getProperty("selenium.core.version");
String coreRevision = p.getProperty("selenium.core.revision");
BuildInfo info = new BuildInfo();
String versionString = String.format("v%s%s, with Core v%s%s. Built from revision %s",
    rcVersion, rcRevision, coreVersion, coreRevision, info.getBuildRevision());
```

Note that this requires a static import:

```java
import static org.openqa.selenium.browserlaunchers.LauncherUtils.getSeleniumResourceAsStream;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it didn't works for me. The 4 Versionstrings are "null"...

Comment: What version are you on, anyway? Does the file exist? What does it look like? It works for me on 2.15.0, called from a junit test written in groovy...

Comment: I'm on version 2.15.0 too and using java with testng. I think the file must exists, because no IOException is thrown...

Comment: I don't understand you guys.  There is no VERSION.txt anywhere in the Selenium .jar files.  Are you talking about the source .jar's or something?

Answer (score -1):

Actual path to file with version in selenium is:

`/META-INF/maven/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java/pom.properties`

```java
Properties p = new Properties();
p.load(LauncherUtils.class.getResourceAsStream("/META-INF/maven/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java/pom.properties"));
p.getProperty("version");`
```