# How to get Selenium version from code

Tags: java, selenium

I have using selenium in my java application as maven dependency.
It's any way to get selenium version from my code?

Comment: You already have your answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8574949/how-can-i-get-the-webdriver-version-during-testrun

Comment: That way is not working. Selenium was changed from that time.

Comment: What have you tried? There is a similar `META-INF/maven/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java/pom.properties` file, which you can parse to get this information.

Comment: Thx, `/META-INF/maven/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java/pom.properties` is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a code snippet to print the all dependency details from the pom file with help of the `maven-model` dependency:

```
File pomfile = new File("./pom.xml");

MavenXpp3Reader reader = new MavenXpp3Reader();

Model model = reader.read(new FileReader(pomfile));

List<Dependency> dependencies = model.getDependencies();

for (Dependency dependency : dependencies) 

{
          
System.out.println("--------------------------------------");

System.out.println("Group Id: "+dependency.getGroupId());

System.out.println("Artifact Id: "+dependency.getArtifactId());

System.out.println("Version: "+dependency.getVersion());

}
```

**Required Dependency**

```
maven-model
4.0.0-alpha-5
```

Answer (score -1):

I write a simple python code like below and run it (for example: python myscripttoshowversion.py) to get version of selenium:

```
from selenium import webdriver

print ("Selenium webdriver Version: %s" % (webdriver.__version__))
```

Result looks like this:

> Selenium webdriver Version: 2.53.6
>
> Process finished with exit code 0