# How to know Selenium version from webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I need to know the selenium version the webdriver is communicating with. I think this could be done before with getEval and Selenium.version, but I cannot find now how to do it.

Is there a way?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get the WebDriver version during Testrun?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8574949/how-can-i-get-the-webdriver-version-during-testrun)

Comment: No, it's not. I want to know the version I am comunication with.

Answer (score 0):

You would have referenced the jar's in your IDE (Eclipse or whatever you are using maybe). Check to build path libraries.

See the highlighted parts in ScreenShot below

https://www.screencast.com/t/b1jUbCN8TOS